# Transform ellipse into general ellipse equation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I transform an ellipse given by

$x(\phi) = c * \sin(\phi) + x_0 \\
y(\phi) = c * \sin(\phi + \phi_0) + y_0 \\
\phi \in [0, 2\pi[$

into the general ellipse equation

$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$

Comment: To ask a proper question on here, please include some of your own attempts to show where you're stuck, allowing people to help you in a more useful manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin{\phi}=\frac{x-x_0}{c}$, solve $\sin{\phi}\cos{\phi_0}+\cos{\phi}\sin{\phi_0}=\sin(\phi+\phi_0)=\frac{y-y_0}{c}$ for $\cos{\phi}$:

$$\frac{y-y_0}{c\sin{\phi_0}}-\frac{x-x_0}{c}\frac{\cos{\phi_0}}{\sin{\phi_0}}=\cos{\phi}$$

And use $1=\cos^2{\phi}+\sin^2{\phi}=(\frac{x-x_0}{c}\cot{\phi_0}-\frac{y-y_0}{c\sin{\phi_0}})^2+(\frac{x-x_0}{c})^2$ to get:

$y_0^2-2yy_0-2\cos(\phi_0)x_0y_0+2\cos(\phi_0)xy_0+y^2+2\cos(\phi_0)x_0y-2\cos(\phi_0)xy+x_0^2-2xx_0+x^2=c^2\sin^2(\phi_0).$

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!!

Comment: @anderstood I did, but I don't have enough reputation for it to show up